Reset channels for two-qubit space
In the paper "Unbiased Simulation of Near-Clifford Quantum Circuits" by Ryan S. Bennink et al. (arXiv) the authors define a Pauli reset ("Pauli measurements followed by Clifford operations conditioned on measurement outcomes").
They claim that there are 6 such operations in the single-qubit case and 30 in the two-qubit case.
For example, the reset channel to $|0\rangle$ in the single-qubit case is (Kraus form) $K_0=|0\rangle\langle0|$, $K_1=|0\rangle\langle1|$, and clearly there are six such operations.
However, I cannot understand why there are 30 in the two-qubit case and what those operations are.
My calculations show that the 60 two-qubit Pauli's eigenstates (4 per each of the 15 two-qubit Pauli matrices) lead only to 28 non-equivalent reset channels. For example, the eigenstates of $IZ$ and $ZI$ are the same. Can anyone help?
